# createMaterialTopTabNavigator inside ScrollView with dynamic height

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-navigation

**Is there any way to create something like a ScrollView with dynamic height?**

Details on what we're trying to do:

We created a Top Tab Bar (using `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`) within a `ScrollView`. Everything works fine, except the height of the ScrollView. Let's assume there are 3 tab screens with different heights: TabScreen1: 800, TabScreen2: 400, TabScreen3: 300... At rendering, the ScrollView takes the greatest height, and when Tab2 or 3 is selected, the height of our ScrollView remains at 800, so there is empty space for scrolling in Tab2 and 3.
[image]

Comment: tell me how you have made the scroll work inside tabNavigator.

Comment: It's just a screen inside your HomeStack.Navigator (`HomeStack = createMaterialTopTabNavigator()`) like `<HomeStack.Screen name="tab_1" ...etc />`. And in tab_1 you can use a `ScrollView` as usual. I also wrapped my scrollview inside a `View` Component with `flex: 1`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I promised, here is how we solved it.

In your class where you have your `ScrollView` you need a state like

```
const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('tab1') //your default (first) tab
```

Later, you want to change that state every time you change tab:

```
<TabsStack.Screen
  name={'tab1'}
  component={
    activeTab === 'tab1' ? Tab1Screen : DefaultScreen
  }
  listeners={{ focus: () => setActiveTab('tab1') }}
/>
```

Now every time a tab is unselected or rather not focused it will show DefaultScreen which is an empty view and has **no height** like:

```
const DefaultScreen = () => (
  <Box
    flex={1}
    py={20}
    alignItems="center"
    justifyContent="center"
    bg="background"
  >
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="white" animating />
  </Box>
)
```

In my case (see question above), every time I switch from Tab1.1.1 to Tab1.1.2, Tab1.1.1 will change to DefaultScreen

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, except now when I switch from the bottom of a screen with more height to one with less height, the entire ScrollView pops up to match the new height. Has anyone solved this?

Comment: @SameerIngavale what do you mean by "pops up" ? Do you mean that it jumps to the top of your ScrollView?

Comment: at first look I didn't understand the solution, then after reading it properly I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, 
Fix the height of the parent widget to the maximum screen height you want that Tab Navigator to have.

```
<ListView or ScrollView>
 <View style={{height:  (width)/(0.8)}} >
    <Tab.Navigator tabBar={(props) => <TabBar {...props} />}>
      <Tab.Screen name="T1" component={T1} />
      <Tab.Screen name="T2" component={T2} />
      <Tab.Screen name="T3" component={T3} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
   </View>
</ ListView or ScrollView>
```

And for tabs do Something like this

T1 ->

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
    <FlatList
      numColumns={3}
      data={allMedia}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      listKey={(post) => `${post.id}D`}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (Anything)}
      scrollEnabled ={false}
    />
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Remember to disable the scroll view Inside the FlatList of tabs and wrap with a ScrollView with nestedScrollEnabled={true}

Answer (score 0):

Use this contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}} inside scroll view

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
...
// your tab
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to put TabNavigator inside ScrollView. Put ScrollView inside of each TabScreen instead

Answering your question: if your ScrollView is the same height as the content then it doesn't scroll. You are probably talking about height of a contentContainer of a ScrollView. And the only wayto set it dynamically is to use `onLayout` to measure content height of currently selected tab, save this number to state and apply it as a height of in `contentContainerStyle` prop of a ScrollView. I don't recommend hacking it this way unless absolutely necessary though

Comment: You got to understand, the TabNavigator is not the only item inside our ScrollView, there is also another TabNavigator above. Furthermore there is a carousel at the Top - I'm going to add an Example to my Question. We also tried applying a height in contentContainerStyle, but it doesn't take it.

Comment: I understand your problem. There is no good support for nested ScrollViews and FlatLists in RN and your setup must already be spamming you warnings. The only thing you can do is to hack your way through. I highly suggest you investigate difference between ScrollView height and contentContainer height. `contentContainerStyle` does perfectly take height

Comment: I think the problem here is that at runtime the ScrollView always ends up taking the height of the content with biggest height no matter what we're passing in. But the good news is that we've solved (or found a workaround for) the problem.  I will post the solution in the next few days - as soon as I have time. Thank you very much for your efforts :)

Comment: glad you found the solution. Beware though ScrollView is not supposed to take any height by itself - you need to define a height for it - either with flex: 1 and definite height parents or by passig height explicitly. If you don't do this and ScrollView expands to the height of the content that means it will not scroll by itself, and will be no different from just View